# Speaker Icon in taskbar is missing

Tags: sound, gnome-panel

I'm totally newbie to Ubuntu after years of MS Windows. Please excuse my mitakes. The icon was located in Gnome Panel 2.30.2. and it adjust the level of sound.

Comment: Do you mean the sound indicator?

Comment: see if you have indicator-sound installed and also check if it is running with system monitor.

Comment: please, add more detail to your question :)!

Answer (score 1):

Just right click on the panel, and select Add to Panel. Scroll down, and look for Indicator applet. Click the Add button. That should add the indicator. If that does not solve your problems, open a terminal, by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>

Type

`rm /home/wissen16/.gconf/apps/panel/`

And log out for the settings to take effect.